# angularjs ng-grid filter lower or higher than the given value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I have looked up for many answers for this issue.But haven't got the solution about this.In the official docs, i can only know how to filter the given search text which put the key "$scope.filterOptions" in the gridOptions.I want the more powerful way to filter like regular searching. can anyone give some way to do that?

Comment: possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17979710/2777098 The answer is specific for filtering >= the given value of 50

Comment: @IsabelHM It seems like to filter data outside the grid first and then inject it into the grid. don't know the performance.BTW, thanks